# Chromecast works while I have NordVPN active. Chromecast does not work when I have mullvad VPN active. Why?

Tags: vpn

I noticed some interesting behavior while trying out VPNs. With NordVPN active, I am still able to connect to my chromecast over wifi. But, with Mullvad VPN active, I can't.

I know NordVPN is still doing *something* because websites will still act as if I am connected via VPN when NordVPN is active.

The behavior from Mullvad VPN is honestly what I would have expected (no connection over wifi to other devices on the wifi because of the VPN), so why does it work with NordVPN?